# Veins: I added extra accident message but can not see the data exchange between nodes

Tags: omnet++

I added extra event like accident in TraCiMobility.cc including the accident message but I can only see the data exchange between nodes for the accident message and can not see the data exchange between nodes with the new "icyroad" event.

When using only "icy road",  I can see the data exchange between the nodes. Where should I add/edit in Veins so that I can see data exchange when both or more events are active?

The .ini is as follows:

```js
*.node[*].veinsmobilityType = "org.car2x.veins.modules.mobility.traci.TraCIMobility"
*.node[*].mobilityType = "TraCIMobility"
*.node[*].mobilityType.debug = true
*.node[*].veinsmobilityType.debug = true
*.node[*].veinsmobility.x = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.y = 0
*.node[*].veinsmobility.z = 1.895

*.node[4].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1
*.node[4].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 45s
*.node[4].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 30s  #30s

*.node[3].veinsmobility.icyroadCount = 1
*.node[3].veinsmobility.icyStart = 15s
*.node[3].veinsmobility.icyDuration = 30s
```

Comment: Did you update the demo program to relay more than just the first message a node receives?

Comment: Hi Christoph;  Yes, I added similar event(icyroad) like accident event in the respective .cc and .h files. It is because I wanted different kinds of events on the road. Is this the correct way to do?

Comment: You need to update the demo program to relay more than just the first message a node receives.

Answer (score 0):

The sample simulation that is included in Veins 4a2 uses an application layer that [only relays the first message it receives](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L55). You will need to change this to a more full-featured application layer to make this work with more than one event type.

Comment: Thank you Christoph Sommer for your suggestion. I will post this as a new question. Sorry for the inconvenience.